# Search powershell by CSV for Computer name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Ive been tasked with the issue of searching a CSV file that has over 1000 computer names in it. I was wondering if there was a way to search AD with Get-ADComputer by the CSV file for the computer names and return the output if they exist in active directory. So far I haven't been able to come up with anything except of doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach through the computer names from the csv, but that could take a while for 1000 computers.

An alternative is to build an LDAP filter from the computernames in the csv, and do it on one operation:

```
$ComputerNames = Import-Csv c:\somedir\computers.csv |
 select -ExpandProperty ComputerName

$NameFilters = $ComputerNames -replace '^','(Name=' -replace '$',')'
$Filter = "'(|$NameFilters)'"

Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $Filter
```

Comment: Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ComputerNames = Import-Csv c:\computers.csv |
 select -ExpandProperty ComputerName

$NameFilters = $ComputerNames -replace '^','(' -replace '$',')'
$Filter = "'(|$NameFilters)'"


Get-ADComputer -LDAPFilter $Filter

Woudl that work? It seems to run but doesnt show the output.

Comment: What's in the $ComputerNames variable? Should be an array of all the computer names.

Comment: The $ComputerNames variable reads the CSV file and outputs each comptuer name.

Comment: I had an extra set of single quotes in the filter.  Try the updated script.

Answer (score 0):

```
Import-CSV MyCSV.CSV | Select-Object *,@{n='InAD';e={$n = $_.Name ; IF (Get-ADComputer -filter {Name -eq $n}) {$True} ELSE {$False}}} | Export-CSV MyNewCSV.CSV
```

On a mega-line. Replace "Name" in "$_.Name" with whatever column header contains the computer name.

(edited to add clarification and full cmdlet name).